# Django many to many recursive relationship

Tags: django, oracle, django-models

I'm not so great with databases so sorry if I don't describe this very well...

I have an existing Oracle database which describes an algorithim catalogue. 
There are two tables algorithims and xref_alg.

Algorithims can have parents and children algorithms. Alg_Xref contains these relationships with two foreign keys - xref_alg and xref_parent.

These are the Django models I have so far from the inspectdb command

```
class Algorithms(models.Model):
    alg_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    alg_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    alg_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    alg_tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    alg_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'algorithms'

class AlgXref(models.Model):
    xref_alg = models.ForeignKey(Algorithms, related_name='algxref_alg' ,null=True, blank=True)
    xref_parent = models.ForeignKey(Algorithms, related_name='algxref_parent', null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'alg_xref'
```

On trying to query AlgXref I encounter this:

```
DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "ALG_XREF"."ID": invalid identifier
```

So the error seems to be that it looks for a primary key ID which isn't in the table.. I could create one but seems a bit pointless. Is there anyway to get around this? Or change my models?

EDIT: So after a bit of searching it seems that Django requires a model to have a primary key. Life is too short so have just added a primary key. Will this have any impact on performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a limitation of the ORM provided by Django. Each model has to have one field marked as `primary_key=True`, if there isn't one, the framework automatically creates an `AutoField` with name `id`.

However, this is being worked on as we speak as part of this year's Google Summer of Code and hopefully will be in Django by the end of this year. For now you can try to use the fork of Django available at https://github.com/koniiiik/django which contains an implementation (which is not yet complete but should be sufficient for your purposes).

As for whether there is any benefit or not, that depends. It certainly makes the database more reusable and causes less headaches if you just add an auto incrementing `id` column to each table. The performance impact shouldn't be too high, the only thing you might notice is that if you have a many-to-many table like this, containing only two `ForeignKey` columns, adding a third one will increase its size by one half. That should, however, be irrelevant as long as you don't store billions of rows in that table.